# Trying to add a offset when something comes into the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I found a jQuery plugin from Remy Sharp which I want to use to add/remove classes when something enters the viewport and triggers again when appearing again. It work's fine but it triggers as soon as it in the viewport, I want to add an effect to the item like a fade-in, this would be hidden basically is if triggers instantly.

I've tried to add a + 200 to the code and that works but it it also +200 when scrolling back, meaning that it will trigger before it enters the viewport when scrolling back. I can't find a way set the + 200 to when it comes from the bottom and - 200 when it comes from the top, this would mean it will always trigger when the element is already a little in viewport.

The goals is to have the following effect:
- element1 scrolls almost out of view
- element1 get's a fade-out-class
- element2 enters the viewport 
- element2 gets a fade-in class

When scrolling up the opposite should happen, I think the code would work for this as it can remove a class when not in the viewport and therefor make it a toggle thing if I am not mistaken. I also want to add a class to another element like a image that fades-in at the same time.

I've tried to change this line (36)

```
top = $el.offset().top,
```

to this

```
top = $el.offset().top + 200,
```

It works but it will cause problems for scrolling up.

I've included a Fiddle with the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/36Lgzdyh/